# Java api running in wildfly stopped responding

Tags: java, wildfly, amazon-linux

I have a java api service deployed in wildfly on Amazon linux, randomly the api calls are not reaching the api-service at all, but the wildfly is up and running, the memory/cpu usage seems normal at this point. I couldn't see any error on the application log.

When I restart wildfly, the application work normally.

Any pointers to debug this issue? Thank you

Wildfly Configuration

```
# General configuration for the init.d scripts,
# not necessarily for JBoss AS itself.
# default location: /etc/default/wildfly

## Location of JDK  
JAVA_HOME="/usr/"

## Location of WildFly
JBOSS_HOME="/opt/wildfly"

## The username who should own the process.
JBOSS_USER=root

## The mode WildFly should start, standalone or domain
JBOSS_MODE=standalone

## Configuration for standalone mode
JBOSS_CONFIG=standalone.xml

## Configuration for domain mode
# JBOSS_DOMAIN_CONFIG=domain.xml
# JBOSS_HOST_CONFIG=host-master.xml

## The amount of time to wait for startup
STARTUP_WAIT=60

## The amount of time to wait for shutdown
SHUTDOWN_WAIT=60

## Location to keep the console log
JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG="/var/log/wildfly/console.log"

## Additionals args to include in startup
# JBOSS_OPTS="--admin-only -b 127.0.0.1"
JBOSS_OPTS="-Djboss.bind.address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  -DConfig=/opt/app-conf/app-conf.properties -DLogDirectory=/var/log/wildfly"
```

Here is the output of ps -ef | grep wildfly

```
/usr//bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /opt/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar -mp /opt/wildfly/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/opt/wildfly -Djboss.server.base.dir=/opt/wildfly/standalone -c standalone.xml -Djboss.bind.address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -DConfig=/opt/app-conf/app-conf.properties -DLogDirectory=/var/log/wildfly
```

Can you help to check if the memory and heap space are right? Or should I increase what could be the optimal value for it?

Comment: Not sure how your doing logging but its possible a fatal error occurred and it shutdown before logging could capture and output it. I would recommend. 1) pipe stdout/err to a log file. 2) Specifically add a args for heap dump and JVM crash logs. 3) Possibly adding shutdown hooks for your application. I would also do those in that order. Unfortunately this specific question isn't well suited to Stack Overflows question policies so its likely to get closed/few answers. Good luck!

Comment: Wildfly allows for a ton of configuration. It's difficult to predict what maybe going wrong without that. It could be helpful if you could provide the config and what your API does.

Comment: I have updated the wildfly configuration

Comment: is there only one instance of wildfly running, no clustering? how are you sure that the api call never reached the server? What error do you get in that case? 404? Do you see logs messages when the api calls are successful? Just something that you can check.

Comment: Yeah only one instance of wildfly is running. I don't see the api call log on the backend, thats how I confirmed it